# Joining table with its self

Tags: mysql, sql

i have question here...

```
Table : history
|id   |transaction|created_at         |merchant_id|
|-----|-----------|-------------------|-----------|
|1    |400        |2015-10-12 11:08:37|33         |
|1    |500        |2015-10-15 09:38:22|33         |
|1    |600        |2015-10-21 14:47:12|22         |
|2    |100        |2015-09-26 10:48:27|31         |
|2    |500        |2015-09-30 11:18:07|27         |
|2    |300        |2015-10-02 17:33:57|31         |
```

i want when im do query:

```
SELECT SUM(a.transaction)/COUNT(a.transaction) AS avg_trans
FROM history AS a GROUP BY a.id, a.merchant_id

Result:
|id    |avg_trans|merchant_id|
|------|---------|-----------|
|1     |450      |33         |
|1     |600      |22         |
|2     |200      |31         |
|2     |500      |27         |
```

then show avg_trans into table history, like this :

```
|id   |transaction|created_at         |avg_trans|merchant_id|
|-----|-----------|-------------------|---------|-----------|
|1    |400        |2015-10-12 11:08:37|450      |33         |
|1    |500        |2015-10-15 09:38:22|450      |33         |
|1    |600        |2015-10-21 14:47:12|600      |22         |
|2    |100        |2015-09-26 10:48:27|200      |31         |
|2    |200        |2015-09-30 11:18:07|500      |27         |
|2    |300        |2015-10-02 17:33:57|200      |31         |
```

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
select h.*,
       (select avg(h2.transaction)
        from history h2
        where h2.id = h.id
       ) as avg_trans
from history h;
```

You can also do this with a `group by`.  However, the above can take advantage of an index on `history(id, transaction)`.  Also note that SQL has the built-in aggregation function `AVG()`, so you might as well use it.

The `group by`/`join` version looks like:

```
select h.*, hh.avg_trans
from history h join
     (select id, avg(h2.transaction) as avg_trans
      from history h2
      where h2.id = h.id
     ) hh
     on h.id = hh.id;
```

Comment: oh,, thanks sir...  i dont know that we can use subquery. awesome.